# Python(/C/Java): How do I divide an integer by an integer, and produce an evenly distributed list of integers?

Tags: algorithm

I have an integer amount of 'somethings', and I want to divide them into groups, each of an integer amount. Not only that, they must be distributed as evenly as possible.

So, let us say for example I have 9 apples (`apples = 9`) and I need to separate them into 6 groups (`groups = 6`). And, let us say that I can't cut an apple, so `apples/groups = 1.5` and thus a set of groups `[1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5,  1.5,  1.5]` will not work. One solution would be `[2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]` or similar. But I need them distributed as evenly as possible, thus the solution must be `[2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]`. Or if it was 7 apples into 5 groups, the solution would be `[2, 1, 2, 1, 1]`.

I am aware that you could find different 'even' distributions, say `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]` in the case of 9 apples into 6 groups. But since neither is *more* evenly distributed, either will do. I simply chose, for the sake of argument, to start with the higher number and alternate as long as possible.

How do I find the solution, given the starting amount and the number of groups I want? [I prefer python, but I understand Java/C/C++, so any will do.]

Background: Since I seem to be getting alot of flack for asking this, here is the reason: I am writing a custom text renderer, and I need to lay out justified text. This means adding and integer amount of pixels to the spacing between words, as evenly as possible. And as fast as possible...

Comment: Can someone at least explain to me what is wrong with this question?

Comment: Homework? Try to think of an algorithm first before trying to implement it as an application.

Comment: I am not so stupid that I can't work out a complex approach. But I need a fast one, and I am trying to figure out if there are any tricks/built in methods that would aid in easily producing a solution

Comment: *let us say for example I have 7 apples (apples = 9)* Uhm... maybe you meant *9 apples* or *(apples = 7)*... as of the downvotes, I would not know the answer is not greatly stated (what is your definition of *evenly distributed*? --answering this question will have a great impact on the potential solutions... is [ 1, 2, 1 ] more/less evenly distributed than [2, 1, 1]?) but it is not worse than many other answers that are not downvoted... good luck

Comment: The speed first of all depends on the algorithm you use for this mathematical problem, thus it is not a programming question. It becomes a programming question if you think about how to implement a chosen algorithm.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Corrected. Thanks. Also, in your example, I suppose they are similar enough. But I think everyone would agree that [2,2,1,1,1,1] is alot less even than [2,1,1,2,1,1].

Comment: @Jeff: The problem is that not everyone thinks that [2,2,1,1,1] is a lot less *even* than [1,2,1,2,1], the first . There is no clear definition of *even*, most everyone would agree that [2,2,2] is more *even* than [1,4,1], but I would have interpreted [a,b,c,d] as a set of quantities without any order and in that sense the original two sets are just as *even*.

Comment: probably, you can tag this as [algorithm] for future reference

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you go through the locations one-by-one, at each allocating the fairest split of the remaining objects, you will get the distribution you want.  For your 9 objects into 6 locations example, this goes:

9 ÷ 6 = 1.5, so allocate 2 apples to the first location (rounds up).

7 ÷ 5 = 1.4, so allocate 1 apple to the second location (rounds down).

6 ÷ 4 = 1.5, so allocate 2 apples to the third location (rounds up).

4 ÷ 3 = 1.33.., so allocate 1 apple to the fourth location (rounds down).

3 ÷ 2 = 1.5, so allocate 2 apples to the fifth location (rounds up).

1 ÷ 1 = 1, so allocate 1 apple to the sixth location.

To get the rounded division of `a` ÷ `b` from C's truncating integer division, you can use `(a + b/2) / b` as long as the summation won't overflow.

Comment: Simply brilliant! So much more straightforward, pythonic, and faster than any approach I tried coding until now!

Answer (score 2):

You divide them into to equal groups and add each remainding element to different group until you run out of elements. Ruling out permutations that's an even distribution. If the order is important then having n elements and k groups add each element from the n % k remainding elements to every n / (n % k) th group. That's as even as it gets.

You really don't need any special tools to do this.

edit:
This can be done while processing the original list and so that it maintains the order. Basically every n / (n % k) sublist has to have n / k + 1 elements. caf's solution is cleaner though.

Comment: This is not homework! Check out the background info I just added. It has to do with implementing text justification in a text renderer. It is a personal project, and I simply assumed that programmers with more experience may know of some builtin python method/library or simply a trick. Gods...

Comment: @Jeff ok, check my edit. You don't need any special tools to do this.